# Not understanding Javascript function binding

Tags: javascript, node.js

I'm writing a Javascript class with a `send` method which gets a promise from other class members and resolves it. The success and error functions passed to it are members of the class. It is not working as expected. The method code:

```
Request.prototype.send = function () {
    if (!this.promise) {
        this.promise = this.api[this.method](this.flatArgsArray, this.options);
        this.promise.then(this.distributeResults, this.distributeErrors);
    } else {
        throw new Error('This request was already answered');
    }
}
```

The `distributeResults` method fails, and the code is:

```
Request.prototype.distributeResults = function (result) {
    if (this.isEntityRequest) {
        var items = result.body[array_names[this.method]];
        items.forEach(this.distributeEntities);
    } else {
        this.callbacks.forEach(function (cb) {
            cb(null, result);
        });
    }
}
```

It fails on the `this.callbacks.forEach` line saying `this.callbacks` is undefined. But the `this.isEntityRequest` had to be true so I debugged and found out that everything starting with `this.` was undefined.

So in the `send` method, when I pass the methods to the promise's `then`, I binded the `distributeResults` method like `this.distributeResults.bind(this)` and it worked. But I'm feeling it redundant. If I have to do that I'd rather define the method as a regular JS function. I thought defining it as a method of the class would save me the binding.

So, if I defined the promise response as a class method, why do I still need to bind it? What about binding am I missing?

Comment: Where is `this.callbacks` defined?

Comment: On a side note, are you mutating the prototype of a native `Request` object? If so _please_ don't do that - it's bad practice to mutate native objects. But if that's a custom object, carry on :)

Comment: Can you show code that is invoking `send` method?

Comment: *"I thought defining it as a method of the class would save me the binding."* There isn't really a concept of "methods" in JavaScript (well, in ES6 we have the method syntax, but still). "Methods" are just properties that hold functions. Functions are their own entities. They don't have strong ties to objects and *there is no autobinding*.

Comment: I recommend to read [You Don't Know JS: this & Object Prototypes](https://github.com/getify/You-Dont-Know-JS/blob/master/this%20&%20object%20prototypes/README.md#you-dont-know-js-this--object-prototypes)